# Problem in an example of Introduction to stochastic processes by Lawler page 25

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

**Example. page 25:** Consider the two-state Markov chain with $S=\{0,1\}$ and P=
$\begin{pmatrix}   1-p & p  \\   q & 1-q  \\   \end{pmatrix}$ where $0< p,q< 1 $ 
Asuume the chain starts in state 0 and let $T$ be the return time to 0. It has shown that $\bar{\pi}=(q/(p+q),p/(p+q))$ and hence 
$$E(T)=\frac{1}{\pi(0)}=\frac{p+q}{q}$$
In this example we can write down the distribution for T explicitly  and verify the above equation For $n>1$
$P(T \geq n)= P(X_1=1,X_2=1,\dots X_{n-1}=1| X_0=0)=p(1-q)^{n-2}$
**I couldn't understand the last equation. Please explain why the $P(T \geq n)=p(1-q)^{n-2}$**

Comment: for example $P(T\geq 3)=P(T=3)+P(T=4)+\dots=p(1-q)q+p(1-q)^2q+\dots$=?

Comment: The event $T\geq n$ requires that in consecutive steps we move from state $0$ to $1$ (with probability $p$) then for the next $n-2$ steps remain in state $1$ (each step with probability $1-q$). Multipying these probabilities gives $p(1-q)^{n-2}$.